# Validating assets api from postman using rest api for azure media service 401 unauthorzed

Tags: azure, mediastream

Follow link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-rest-connect-with-aad

Get: https://mediatest1.restv2.SoutheastAsia.media.azure.net/api/Assets

Header:
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
x-ms-version: 2.19
Host:media.windows.net
Authoriztion: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImtpZCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyJ9.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.WmtlWAuY_UxQDjsx7p7N7hQBP061Mx_CMlMP51bA7yXF4ac7Nr46gs1nrj-lTTKEoEuJXb-k-GiMtcfvDc5ooeEHO-IAC3LIFItlQBtgQ1jcAM3QtwXEY8CLJ7yG6XXCk4GtIDLCrcXfh5hg2qdI06gZFdabeEA2aQDrqFbJFj-u4UIkvnPMklM5xs3szHceYQFtiVbblzS8fTBQfkHdYEDWLQunpwH-_GT5h4O_YVtoElmKWjzHgBDO9rA4XgejWFLNV5KzKSjd31IW2EzFb9DWpdaJP1P8ou9pJ_fQvLMAfzk73F4eR785VIPvOP3gfwgw2OSaboFUO_o1gFpADA

Response:
401

Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
request-id: 3e93ef9f-cb7e-4921-8e99-b911469d0020
x-ms-request-id: 3e93ef9f-cb7e-4921-8e99-b911469d0020
access-control-expose-headers: request-id, x-ms-request-id
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2021 14:20:47 GMT

it is working fine when i using azure sdk

Looking for help as i am struggling for last 6 hours

Thank you in advance